# Vectorizing a symbol with more than one value in a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, symbols, equation

I would like to export the answers of an equation with the order of 2 into a vector. The input is `R01`and the variable is `n`.
The problem is where I want to "double" the symbol for each step of `i`, I get the following error:

> In an assignment A(I)=B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
>   same.

There will be no error if I do not use a for loop. What is my mistake and how can I modify it that I could get the data as a matrix or vector.

```
R01=[0.07941 0.07942 0.07952 0.07946 0.07951 0.07947]

syms n 
for i=1:length(R01)
    eq3=((1+n)^2)*R01(i)-(n-1)^2
    sol1=solve([eq3]);
    nsol(i)=double(sol1);
end
```

Comment: There are so many questions already explaining this error message, [for example this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33871530/2732801)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I understood the problem but the solution was not clear for me. However, understanding helped to modify it for better. I do not know whether the solution I have written in a post is an efficient way or not, but it somehow works.
any suggestions to make it more efficienct?

Comment: Alternative solutions are using a cell array `nsol{i}=double(sol1);` or a matrix `nsol(i,:)=double(sol1);`. The later works only when you always have the same number of solutions.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to solve the problem (by Daniel):

```
syms n 
for i=1:length(R01)
    eq3=((1+n)^2)*R01(i)-(n-1)^2
    sol1=solve([eq3]);
    nsol(i,:)=double(sol1);
end
```